# my RPM package requires 2 already installed shared libraries

Tags: rpmbuild

I'm looking for help about making rpm packages.

I just created my first RPM package with rpmbuild.
This package is simple. It has just to copy several config files and one executable.

I cannot install this .rpm because 2 shared librairies used by the executable are required.

These librairies are already installed but they are not linked with another .rpm package because I build them from one of my projects. There are located in the /usr/myproject/lib directory.

I tried to put symbolic links to /lib and /usr/lib, tried also to run a "ldconfig" update from a .conf file which contains the /usr/myproject/lib directory, and tried to update the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable without any success.

I know I can ignore dependencies using the -nodeps command line option but I'd like in the next step to create my own yum repository but yum do not allow to install a package if the dependencies are not fulfilled.

I would also prefer to keep the automatic dependency feature of rpmbuild enabled.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Package these 2 libraries in another RPM, then you can install both RPMs in one rpm -i call.

Comment: Yes it works thx a lot ! I was expecting other solution but it seems it is the only one.